# Подскажите плагин валидации Jquery, чтобы выводить сообщений в свой блок

Tags: jquery

Подскажите плагин валидации Jquery, чтобы выводить сообщений в свой блок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

стандартный jquery validate , параметр errorPlacement

Comment: Это он? https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate
не нахожу тут такого параметра

Comment: в этом плагине есть valid callback. вы можете легко написать там вывод ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Содержит много настроек, гибко настраиваемый.